# List printers from command line to text file

Tags: windows, command-line, printer

Is there a command that can be used from the command line to output a list of the printers installed and their location, if mapped, to a text file? Or perhaps a program that I can run from the command line that would do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Windows XP use prntmngr:

```
PRNMNGR -l >> C:\printers.txt
```

In Windows XP SP3 Vista and beyond (you need to install powershell v1 manually) , use PowerShell:

```
get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | ft name, systemName, shareName >> c:\printers.txt
```

Note: You MAY get an error if you attempt to write the file to C:\ on Vista+, depending on your rights, and how PowerShell was spawned.

For Windows 2000:

The `PrnMngr.vbs` file from XP (located in the `/Windows/System32` folder) does work on Windows 2000.  Just find and copy it over to the 2000 machine from an XP machine and run it with:

```
cscript prnmngr.vbs -l >> c:\printers.txt
```

I found it wouldn't run from my user's desktop for some reason, but when I copied the .VBS to the root of C: it ran fine.

Comment: Worked beautifully!

Comment: In windows XP SP3 you can manually install Powershell c1 and it will also work there.

Answer (score 22):

I use:

```
wmic printer list brief
```

OR

```
wmic printer get name
```

This just shows a short list of printer attached to the system you run the command on.  It will also show what computer a printer is connected to if there's a network printer.

You can also use this to get a very detailed list of configuration for each printer installed on a system:

```
wmic printer list full
```

To output it to a text file, append this to the end of the command:

```
 >>"[directory]\[filename].txt"
```

Example:

```
wmic printer list brief >> c:\users\admin\documents\printerlist.txt
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you don't want to use PS in win7 (I have an application that lets me do administrative work in the background on remote PCs, but it doesn't use powershell). The XP visual basic scripts mentioned can be found in the following folder for Win7:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Windows 8 / Server 2012, there is a `get-printer` PowerShell cmdlet:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918358%28v=wps.630%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Note: For Windows XP, be sure to change the default script host to CScript first

```
C:\CScript //H:CScript
```

otherwise you will get a message telling you to do so and your printers.txt file will be blank.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my solution (in AutoHotKey):

```
;******************
;ALLOCATING CONSOLE
;******************
; cmd calls hidden

global cPid
DetectHiddenWindows, on
Run, %comspec% /k ,,Hide UseErrorLevel,cPid
WinWait, ahk_pid %cPid%,, 1
DllCall("AttachConsole","uint",cPid)
hCon:=DllCall("CreateFile","str","CONOUT$","uint",0xC0000000,"uint",7,"uint",0,"uint",3,"uint",0,"uint",0)


;******* GET PRINTER NAMES **********

AllPrintersNameClearArray := strSplit(StrReplace(StrReplace(StrReplace(StrReplace("|" StrReplace(StrReplace(StrReplace(RunWaitOne("wmic printer get name"),"  ","")," `r",""),"`r",""),"|NAME`n",""),"`n","|"),"||","",All),"|","`n"),"`n")

RunWaitOne(command) {

    objShell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
    objExec := objShell.Exec(command)
    strStdOut := ""
    while, !objExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strStdOut := objExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
    return %strStdOut%
}

; **** Clean at the end *****

Finish:
DllCall("CloseHandle", "uint", hCon)
DllCall("FreeConsole")
Process, Close, %cPid%
ExitApp
return
```

Comment: What language is this? Please write more about how this works.

Comment: @stomy this is an Autohotkey script.

Answer (score 0):

In **PowerShell** *ISE* you can run this to see a list of all installed printers.

`[System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings]::InstalledPrinters`

See the **dot.net** [PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters) for more info.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you say anything more than this? While I think this is technically an answer, it leaves a lot to the imagination and as such isn't a high-quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since WMI is being depreciated, I will use CIM in powershell:

```
Get-CIMInstance CIM_Printer | Format-Table Name,SystemName,ShareName >>printers.txt
```